# Uploading to pastebin

Tags: c++, libcurl, pastebin, trinitycore

Plain and simple: I'm generating a list of integers from a database and I need to upload it to Pastebin.com. Here is my code:

```
curl_global_init(CURL_GLOBAL_ALL);
if (CURL* curl = curl_easy_init()) {
    std::ostringstream postField;
    postField << "api_user_key=" << "&" << "api_option=paste" << "&" << "api_paste_private=1" << "&";
    postField << "api_paste_name=GuidSet" << "&" << "api_paste_expire_date=10M" << "&";
    postField << "api_paste_format=text" << "&" << "api_dev_key=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX" << "&" << "api_paste_code=";
    for (std::set<uint32>::const_iterator itr = resultSet.begin(); itr != resultSet.end(); ++itr) {
        postField << *itr;
        if (itr != --resultSet.end())
            postField << ",";
    }

    struct MemoryStruct chunk;
    chunk.memory = (char*)malloc(1);
    chunk.size   = 1;

    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_URL, "http://pastebin.com/api/api_post.php");
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    char* postStr = curl_easy_escape(curl, postField.str().c_str(), postField.str().length());
    printf("POST parameters: %s\n", postStr);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, postStr);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_NOBODY, 0);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEFUNCTION, WriteMemoryCallback);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_WRITEDATA, (void*)&chunk);
    curl_easy_setopt(curl, CURLOPT_USERAGENT, "TrinityCore GuidBot/1.0");

    curl_easy_perform(curl);
    curl_easy_cleanup(curl);

    self->_parentThread.sendCommand("PRIVMSG %s :%s: Finished, data available at %s",
        searchParams.targetRoom.c_str(), searchParams.actionInvoker.c_str(), chunk.memory);

    if (chunk.memory)
        free(chunk.memory);
    curl_free(postStr);
}
curl_global_cleanup();
```

However, when executing that code, i always get this:

```
* About to connect() to pastebin.com port 80 (#0)
*   Trying 72.20.36.113...
* connected
* Connected to pastebin.com (72.20.36.113) port 80 (#0)
> POST /api/api_post.php HTTP/1.1
User-Agent: TrinityCore GuidBot/1.0
Host: pastebin.com
Accept: */*
Content-Length: 609
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

* upload completely sent off: 609 out of 609 bytes
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< Server: nginx
< Date: Sun, 28 Oct 2012 11:21:33 GMT
< Content-Type: text/html
< Transfer-Encoding: chunked
< Connection: keep-alive
< Vary: Accept-Encoding
<
* Connection #0 to host pastebin.com left intact
* Closing connection #0
Bad API request, invalid api_option
```

Is there anything I'm obviously doing wrong ? The chunk that should be pasted has to look like "48,50,59,...etc"

Comment: I can't really help you but, I think you will have a MUCH easier time using an actual C++ library like libHTTP, http://sourceforge.net/projects/libhttp/

Comment: @111111 Thank you, but I'd prefer to stay away as much as possible from boost, which I guess it uses, basing myself off the examples. Am I correct ?

Comment: No idea, but why avoid boost, it really is one of the finest C++ library around? and libHttp is abstraction above boost.asio it should affect your code at all.

Comment: I'm going to deploy this app on a machine where i should not install boost :| Even if I use it in other projects, this is a setup requirement :/

Comment: You don't set the user key(on the 4th line of the code example): `postField << "api_user_key=" << "&" << ... `. Perhaps this is a requirement for pastbin api.

Comment: statically link it then. If you can get curl you can get boost.

Comment: @diamenh: according to the spec, it is not, but i still get the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved it myself, the problem wasnt lying in CURL, but in streaming parameters, although printf'ing stuff didnt show up any space being inserted.